# Display order count using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I show my table structure below. I want the record like the second structure. Please help me to get this using oracle or SQL.

```
FLd_Date        Fld_Via Fld_Amt
11/1/2013       cash    100.26
11/2/2013       online  123.00
11/3/2013       cash    32.00
11/4/2013       cash    234.00
11/5/2013       cash    125.00
11/6/2013       online  125.00
11/7/2013       cash    200.00
11/8/2013       online  111.00
11/9/2013       online  143.00
11/10/2013      cash    155.00
11/11/2013      online  12.00
11/12/2013      online  142.00
```

I want the output like this

```
mode    count   total
cash    6   846.26
online  6   656
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select fld_via as mode, 
       count(*) as count,
       sum(fld_amt) as total
from your_table
group by fld_via
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
select
    Fld_Via as "mode",
    count(*) as "count",
    sum(Fld_Amt) as "total"
from
    YourTable
Group by Fld_Via
```

Comment: check your query.. why cash in select query -1